# How to achieve coverage reports like Ruby-Rails in Django-Python with coverage.py?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, django, coverage.py

We do coverage reports with the famous and possible the only solution in `python` world i.e. `coverage.py`

Now,
What we acheive with `coverage.py` is this : 
[image]

Where as what we could achieve with `ruby-rails` is :
[image]

**So, my question is how do you get more detailed coverage reports with `coverage.py` ?**

[ Or any other tool in the python django world ]

**Note:**

- `coverage run manage.py test --settings=project.test_settings`
- Generate the report by `coverage html`
- Should / Can I pass in extra parameters to `coverage` while generating report ?

Comment: Did you see https://github.com/relevance/rcov

Comment: Can you suggest something similar in the Python world ?

Comment: Sorry, i misread. Don't know much of python

Comment: jenkins + django-jenkins works for us.

Comment: @YugalJindle: I'm very interested in adding features to coverage.py, but I don't see what you are asking for.  You describe the Rails report as "more detailed," but it looks like it has all the same information as the Python report?  I see hits/line, but I don't understand how that is helpful?

Comment: @NedBatchelder Both the tools possess same data underneath, but `coverage.py` can be produce more aggregated information just like the rails coverage report. But I don't understand why it doesn't. Also, I don't find any option how to do that ?

Comment: @NedBatchelder Being useful, is a subjective term. That said, we have an example of `cobertura code coverage for jenkins` shows even more info and aggregated staats like conditional coverage, etc. 

What wonders me is that why is a dedicated tool limited ?

Comment: @YugalJindle: all tools are limited, in that they are finite, and built to do whatever their author and his vocal users want it to do.  I'd love to know specifically what you would like to see.  The image you put in the question isn't helping me.  You describe the rails tools as "more aggregated", but it shows two files, just as the coverage report shows four files?

Comment: @NedBatchelder in that case :: (1) Search Box [ Big projects have lots & lots of files ], (2) Conditional Coverage [ Like cobertura ], (3) hits/line.

Seems like a debate topic :D

Comment: @NedBatchelder So, if the answer is that `it can be done`, but not yet done out of any `reason x`, then please answer this question with that `reason x`. [ That answers the question ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) A search box seems useful, no one has ever suggested it before!

2) Conditional coverage: coverage.py has a --branch switch that enables branch coverage, is this what you are looking for?

3) Hits/line: is this how many times each line was executed? I've never seen it aggregated like this.  I don't understand how I would use that statistic in my own work.  Can you help me understand why people want to know the averaged hits/line?

Comment: So, (1) You already agree. (2) There can be more then 1 condition to follow a path. This creates the difference when we say code coverage doesn't ensures no bug. If we have a test for all conditions on a pivot its high-quality. [ `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage#Modified_condition.2Fdecision_coverage` ] And then lastly (3) this is more of an aggregation like average, higher hits/line the more rigorously code is tested. Lets imaging saying 5 hits/line on a 500 line of code. In that we are saying every line is executed 5 times on an average and all tests pass.

Comment: Right now we have only `coverage percentage` - I can cover all the code by `True` and `False`. Whereas if a condition is affected by `n variables`, then there are n ways the code has to behave. That motivation gets lost since we already have 100% coverage and that is all coverage.py gives us.

Comment: You can go through the tool used in `ruby-rails` - from which I have quoted the image in the question.

Comment: @YugalJindle: it's true, coverage.py doesn't provide MCDC measurements.  I don't know how to implement MCDC. :(  As far as I know, the rcov doesn't implement it either, in fact, it doesn't even seem to support branch coverage.

Comment: Yes, `rcov` doesn't seems to implement it. But `cobertura code coverage for jenkins` does that [ You can use that for reference ]. Now, even apart from `MCDC` we still have (1) and (3) - that can be done. `Coverage.py` is a wonderful tool, could be much better if we have the above 3 features. It will help the whole python community.

Comment: Are you planning to add these features ?

Comment: @YugalJindle: I generally add features to coverage.py when I get a sense that a number of people want them.  Thanks for letting me know what you'd like, I'll take that into account in the future.